# Yum: What defines the repo a package gets pulled from if the same package is contained in multiple repos?

Tags: yum, rpm, repository

On any given box that has subscriptions to multiple repos

```
yum list available --showduplicates foo
```

gives me:

```
foo.x86_64    0.0.1-1    dev-repo
foo.x86_64    0.0.1-1    test-repo
```

What is the logic that yum uses to determine which package to download? I know in the end, that, if the packages are the same, it shouldn't matter, but I'm still interested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In cases where everything is truly identical, as in your example, [Yum resolves such conflicts alphabetically](http://lists.baseurl.org/pipermail/yum/2007-August/021169.html).

Comment: That's interesting, but does your link talks about packages with different _names_ but that provide the same _content_. If packages have the same name, does it resolve alphabetically based on repo?

Comment: If Yum's behavior is consistent with what is described in my link, it should resolve conflicts alphabetically based on anything it can. In your example, the only thing it can differentiate based on is the repo name. Of course, that's a big 'if'; I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: I'll take this as it seems to be correct.